# Attempting to use /execute unless to stop carrot on a stick right click detection while holding specific item (1.20.1)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm basically trying to set carrot on a stick rightclick detection to not activate when a player is holding a stick, preferrably one with a specific name.

Game version is 1.20.1, running on Fabric version 0.88.1, with the Essentials mod and WorldEdit.

The world is hosted via Essentials, and not run by me. The only changes to the world from the creation menu were to set the default gamemode to creative.

Currently, I'm just trying to get the command to work (or rather not work) when holding a stick, but I don't seem to be able.

This was the original command:

`execute as @a[scores={crrt=1..}] run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1 2 false`

And this is how I've modified it:

`execute as @a[scores={crrt=1..}] run execute unless data entity @s SelectedItem.id=minecraft:stick run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1 255 false`

Both are in repeating, always active command blocks.

After modification, the command still runs the way it originally did, but the "is holding stick" clause doesn't seem to be stopping it. Also, another command I have set up that gives me glowing when I hold a stick and right click, is still working fine after I updated the command shown.

I think the main problem is the syntax of the SelectedItem, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help?

Comment: From another question (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376554/how-do-i-detect-a-player-holding-an-item-with-nbt-data), you could try `... run execute unless @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stick"}}] run effect ...`